# Changing content on a page using javascript via a url string

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm a designer not a JS coder so any help would be great on this.

Using javascript or jquery how would I replace content on a page via a string in the url?

So if content 'A' is just the normal content via this `http://www.example.com` and if 'A' is replaced by content 'B' via this `http://www.example.com/index.html?content=b`.

example:

content A

```
<div id="video-player">
vimeo code
</div>
```

to be replaced with content B

```
<div id="video-player">
youtube code
</div>
```

via a string in the url like so http://www.example.com/index.html?player=youtube
if there is no string in the url then it will default and just show the vimeo code

edit

ok this is what is on my html page now

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="video-player">
vimeo
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and in js page

```
window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&')[0].split('content=')[1]
var content_value = window.location.hash.substring(1) // For hashses OR
var content_value = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&')[0].split('content=')[1] // For ?
if (content_value === "b") {
  $('#video-player').html(vimeo_code);
} else {
  $('#video-player').html(youtube_code);
```

is that right?

Comment: be more precise. you want to load http://www.example.com/index.html?content=b somewhere in the page ? Or read the URL, see if you find "content=b" and then display somehting somewhere ?

Comment: so if there is no string in the url I just want it to show content 'A' but if there is string in the url like content=b then I want the content of 'A' to be replaced with 'B'.

it will be a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest wat to do this would be to use a hash tag. You could use a `?` but it is harder to implement. So instead of `index.html?content=b` use `index.html#b` and then you can reference to that by using `window.location.hash.substring(1)` which would give you `b` in your scenario. Then you can use an if statement to check this value and adjust the content accordingly.

Alternatively, if you **need** to use `?` then you can use this `window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('content=')[1]` but it is not guaranteed to work in every situation, especially if you have more than one variable there. For multiple variables you would use

```
window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&')[0].split('content=')[1]
```

Your **complete code** will now look like this:

```
$(function () {
  var youtube_code, vimeo_code, content_value;
  youtube_code = "The code for Youtube goes here";
  vimeo_code = "The code for Vimeo goes here";
  content_value = (typeof window.location.href.split('player=')[1] !== "undefined") ? window.location.href.split('player=')[1] : "";

  if (content_value === "youtube") {
    $('#video-player').html(youtube_code);
  } else {
    $('#video-player').html(vimeo_code);
  }
});
```

You could also use some `else if`s if you wanted more content options. Use one of the top two lines depending on what option you chose.

**EDIT**: changed code to the complete code (and optimised a bit). You do not need to add anything else to this apart from changing the `youtube_code` and `vimeo_code` to the correct values.

**EDIT**: optimised and made it check if there is actually `player=` in the url.

Comment: A ha, yes. I thought it might be this. Let me figure out a way to fix this and change my code ...

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 is very old. Include this instead: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Try going to your link and see what happens. That is why it isn't working :P

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js this works and I have changed it to the one you suggested but it is still the same... nothing displaying unlike the one you showed me in the link above

Comment: Do you have it in a onload wrapper? And can you delete some of your old comments as this is getting extremely long.

Comment: have deleted some, no i have it as you have on jsfiddle.net/b4rsd

Comment: that has done it.... Im sorry for doing your head in for the night but you have been great

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ajax and xml. Put xml files in your dropbox folder where you can edit the url at any time.

The ajax will update the value without refresh the browser if user select an option.

Good things is you are able to update the url from your mobile phone without login to html editor / website cms and you can use other feature as well.